# What does the double-backslash \\ mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm trying to figure out what  `\\` means in Haskell?

I've got a program that runs perfectly when compiled, implying that `\\` is a built-in function, since it's not defined anywhere in the program. However, in GHCi, if I try to use it in the same manner, I get an error saying it's not in the scope.

Does it mean something special in each context?

Here is my code;

```
module Main where

import Data.List

numbersA = [1, 105, 103, 7, 4, 102, 3, 101, 107, 8, 9]

numbersB = [6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 5, 3, 2, 4]

type Number = Integer

type Run = [Number]

extractRuns :: [Number] -> [Run]
extractRuns [] = []
extractRuns xs = run : extractRuns xs'
                   where run = buildRun (head xs) (tail xs)
                         xs' = xs \\ run

buildRun :: Number -> [Number] -> Run
buildRun seed numbers
  | endRun    = [seed]

  | otherwise = seed : buildRun seed' numbers'
                  where endRun     = successors == []
                        successors = filter (.#. seed) numbers
                        numbers'   = numbers \\ [seed]
                        seed'      = head successors

(.#.) :: Number -> Number -> Bool
x .#. y = x /= y && abs (x - y) < 10

runs = extractRuns numbersA

main = print runs
```

Comment: Try [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) first?

Comment: I always try Google first... but Hoogle? Never heard of it... Thanks! It has my answer!

Comment: Or load up your module in GHCi and do `:i (\\)`

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: `(\\)` isn't in the `Prelude`, though -- OP would have to know to load `Data.List` first.

Comment: @amindfv: It's in scope after loading: http://pastebin.com/Lx1mwi02

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Right, but OP said it was out of scope for them in ghci -- they must not have loaded the module.

Comment: @amindfv I'm pretty sure I said "or load up your module in GHCi". I can even make a screenshot, because it says so four lines up.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\\` is the [list difference operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:-92--92-). You can use it in GHCi you just have to import `Data.List` first.

```
Prelude> :m Data.List
Prelude Data.List> [1..5]\\[3,4]
  [1,2,5]
```

On a sidenote, this is why I'd suggest avoiding mass imports like `import Data.List` and to be more specific `import Data.List ( (\\) )` so you can be more aware of just what you're importing.

Answer (score 10):

It is the [list difference operation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3a-92--92-).  Figuring things like this out is easy if you know to use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5C%5C).

Comment: Just heard of it. I will consult Hoogle always before posting questions. Thank you